# ios 8 UILocalNotificaion vibrations on silent mode

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, silent, vibration

I'm trying to stop the iphone from vibrating in the silent mode. so,how to stop UILocalNotificaion vibrations on silent mode programmatically.

What I want is to vibrate normally when ring mode is on and not to in the silent case. I know that can be done by disabling the setting>sound> vibrate on silent. Is it possible to change the UILocalNotificaton setting to do that automatically (By code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a UILocalNotification is launched, it is not up to your process to decide how it should or should not behave. This relies only on the OS's notification center and might change according to user preferences. The only thing you control is the `UIUserNotificationType`(Badge / Sound / Alert) you're registering for when calling `registerUserNotificationSettings:`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want is to vibrate normally when ring mode is on and not to in the silent case. I know that can be done by disabling the setting>sound> vibrate on silent. Is it possible to change the UILocalNotificaton setting to do that automatically (By code).

Comment: You can try to play around with soundName property but you won't be able to differentiate the behavior between silent and non silent modes AFAIK

Comment: Is there a way to find out whenever the silent mode is enabled in the background and without enabling the audio play background permissions.

Comment: That would mean your process would have to be running in the background which means you need a good reason for it. This is not a good enough reason though.